# Attempting to delete all nodes+rels throws "Expected to be in a transaction but wasn't"

Tags: clojure, neo4j

I'm working in Clojure, against a neo4j database using the neocons library.

I have a test fixture that tears down the nodes and relationships created after each unit test, with the following Cypher query:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r?]-() DELETE n,r
```

This works fine on my workstation, however my Travis CI build fails with "Expected to be in a transaction but wasn't" - see http://travis-ci.org/#!/warrenseymour/workflow/jobs/2477506

I'm using the same version and edition of neo4j in both places, why does one complain about (lack of) transactions when the other does not?

Comment: so you use 1.8.RC1 in both places, you don't go with the default neo4j installed by travis.ci ?

Comment: That's right; travis only provides version 1.6 right now, and I'm using queries that require 1.8

Comment: does your Travis build repeatedly fail? Looks like the Neo4j-Server thread management (tx's are bound to threads) gets mixed up?

Comment: Just as a side note, travis-ci.org provides Neo4J 1.7.

Comment: travis VMs are single core and not particularly powerful so sometimes they reveal concurrency issues that never can be reproduced on developer machines (that increasingly have 4 or at least 2 cores). To tell more I need to run your test suite in a local copy of travis VMs. I've never seen this particular exception with Neocons' test suite, though. We have a bunch of tests that run Cypher queries.

Answer (score 3):

Warren,

I am the author of Neocons and one of the travis-ci.org core team members. I tried reproducing your issue in a local VM that is a subset of our production images.
With Neo4J Server 1.8.RC1, lein test reports just 1 failure (in test-find) and no 5xx responses from Neo4j.

I tried 1 and 4 core VMs as well as an 8 core physical machine.

You can use [Sous Chef](https://github.com/michaelklishin/sous-chef), the project we use to develop our CI environment, with our [production image for JVM languages](http://files.travis-ci.org/boxes/provisioned/travis-jvm.box) (~ 3 GB) to investigate.

Note that Neo4J is not started on boot.

Filing an issue for Neo4J where we can continue more detailed investigation may be a good idea, too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was in the process of putting together a Travis worker in order to perform further analysis. Your heads up on the required resources for doing this is very much appreciated. I will update this question and raise a Neo4J ticket (if necessary) upon my further findings.